# Issue regarding converting of Arraybuffer of image to image and displaying it in html page

Tags: node.js, ejs, arraybuffer

I have my js code as

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) { 
        var sql="SELECT image FROM images WHERE img_id=2"; 
        connection.query(sql, function(err, result){
            if(result.length <= 0)
                message = "Profile not found!";
            console.log(result);
            res.render('image.ejs',{data:result});
   });
    });
```

and the image.ejs code is:

```
<html>
    <head>
         <title>Images</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%= data %>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I have runned it I just got the response like
`[object Object]`
but I need to my image to get displayed.will you guys help me out?

Comment: Did you try using JSON.stringify(result)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `ArrayBuffer/Buffer` can't be a value for an `img` tag, what you can do is `base64` encode the image, and display it

```
res.render('image.ejs',{ data: result[0].image.toString('base64') });
```

Now on your HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
         <title>Images</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src='data:image/png;base64,<%= data %>' />
    </body>
</html>
```

If your images have different extensions, you can use: [file-type](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type) package on the buffer and add the image type to the data passed to `res.render`

```
const imageBuffer = result[0].image;
const { mime } = await FileType.fromBuffer(imageBuffer)

res.render('image.ejs', { data: imageBuffer.toString('base64'), mime });
```

```
<img src='data:<%= mime %>;base64,<%= data %>' >
```

Comment: When I am using "file-type" package,I'm getting an error like 'fileType is not a function' when I am running the code

Comment: Did you install file type package and required it?

Comment: yes,I installed and required it.```var app = require("express")(); 
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var mysql = require('mysql');
var filetype = require('file-type');                                                                          con.query(sql, function(err,result){
            const imageBuffer = result[0].image;
            const  {mime}  = filetype(imageBuffer);
            res.render('recipes_response', { data: imageBuffer.toString('base64'), mime,recipes:result1 });

Comment: you're calling it: `filetype` and I'm using `fileType`, change the name of your variable.

Comment: Even though am getting the same error after changing too

Comment: `fileType` changed the API, the current API is now `await FileType.fromBuffer(buffer)`